# Finalfit does produce a table but without expected formatting

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make a table of my linear regression results. I am trying to use package finalfit. The table produced by the command (in the similar named package) should include formatting that make the table ready to publish, like the first table in this page: https://finalfit.org/. With my code, the resulting table, however, does not include such formatting. It includes the columns, rows, and the titles but no formatting. I did not find any posts with a similar issue. I have tried the code below in R script and I have tried the code in RMarkdown and to knit it there to a word document but the result looks the same, which is not a pretty table and lacks all the formatting that should be there. Does someone have a clue why the formatting is missing from my output?

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)

data(colon) # from survival::colon
explanatory = c("age", "sex", "obstruct", "perfor")
dependent = 'time'
table1 <- colon %>%
  finalfit(dependent, explanatory)
table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried knitting the R Markdown document to PDF?

All the options for formatting in Word and PDF are detailed here:
https://finalfit.org/articles/export.html